# How to set a key with C-x 8 prefix?

Tags: emacs

Say I'd like to re-bind `C-x 8 x` to `ξ`. So I do:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 8 x") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "ξ")))
```

but it doesn't work: it still inserts the default x sign. Then I tried both:

```lisp
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-x 8 x"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 8 x") nil)
```

none gives any effect.

**Edit**:

Here's what I'm using now for Greeks:

```lisp
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "a" [?α])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "b" [?β])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "g" [?γ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "d" [?δ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "e" [?ε])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "z" [?ζ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "h" [?η])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "o" [?θ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "i" [?ι])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "k" [?κ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "l" [?λ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "m" [?μ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "n" [?ν])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "x" [?ξ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "p" [?π])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "r" [?ρ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "s" [?σ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map (kbd "M-s") [?ς])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "x" [?ξ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "t" [?τ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "y" [?υ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "f" [?φ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "v" [?χ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "j" [?ψ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "w" [?ω])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "A" [?Α])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "B" [?Β])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "G" [?Γ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "D" [?Δ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "E" [?Ε])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "Z" [?Ζ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "H" [?Η])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "O" [?Θ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "I" [?Ι])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "K" [?Κ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "L" [?Λ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "M" [?Μ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "N" [?Ν])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "X" [?Ξ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "P" [?Π])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "R" [?Ρ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "S" [?Σ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "T" [?Τ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "Y" [?Υ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "F" [?Φ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "V" [?Χ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "J" [?Ψ])
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "W" [?Ω])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the key in `iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map`. Such as:

```
(eval-after-load 'iso-transl
  '(define-key iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "x" "ξ"))
```

That's because `C-x 8` is actually defined in `key-translation-map`, which overrides the global map.

Comment: Doesn't work: on start up I get `Symbol's value as variable is void: iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map` and hence `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (lambda nil (interactive) (insert "ξ")) 1)
  (lambda nil (interactive) (insert "ξ"))(nil)` when trying to input the thing.

Comment: I also tried `(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map> t") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "ξ")))` and `(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map t") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "ξ")))` -- none works.

Comment: sure, you need to to make sure it's loaded before you use it (by using `(require 'iso-transl)` first, for example). I'm modifying the snippet to delay the key definition.

Comment: now it doesn't complain about the map -- but still doesn't work -- when I try to insert a thing -- it still gives same error. ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found another way:

```
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "x" [?ξ])
```

[reference](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrefixKey#toc2).